# Spring mvc validation

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

How to display validation error messages in jsp **without** returning a new ModelAndView object.

I am able to get the error messages when I return a new ModelAndView but my app requires that I return the same jsp page using **redirect** from controller .

When I use redirect I'll be redirected to the jsp page but I won't get the error messages .

So I want to display error messages in the same jsp page that is used to send the form data to controller

Comment: Have a look at [RedirectAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Answer (score 4):

If the BindingResult has errors you flash attributes and redirect. If you want to use a value like id in the redirect url like redirect:/doctor/editPatient/{id} you should add it to the RedirectAttributes like below. You can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doctor/doEditPatientDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editPatientDetails(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value = "user") @Valid User user,
        BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr, Principal principal) {
    if (null != principal) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user", result);
            attr.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            attr.addAttribute("id", user.getId());
            return "redirect:/doctor/editPatient/{id}";
        }
    }
        .
        .
        .

    return "redirect:/doctor/patients";
}
```

}

and then in your other method you check for the attribute you flashed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doctor/editPatient/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showEditPatient(Model model, @ModelAttribute("id") String id, Principal principal) {
    if (null != principal) {
        Credential credentials = credentialsRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());

        User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
        if (null == user || null == credentials.getUserId()
                || !Objects.equals(user.getDoctorId(), credentials.getUserId())) {
            return "redirect:/doctor/patients";
        }

        //this is used for redirected errors
        if (!model.containsAttribute("user")) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
        }


        .
        .
        .
    }

    return "/doctor/editPatient";
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try n get u back